# Azure KeyValut Secret Expired Event Not Getting Fired

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I am creating an event subscription for KeyVault expiry.
In this screen, I can't type name of the topic. Why is it already populated with a topic name?

[image]

Following screen is from my producation instance and I can see a text box where I can type the name of the topic.

[image]

If I go ahead and create a subscription based on already selected topic (screen1), My secret expired event does not trigger. Any help please.

I can't see anything in the application insight, only this graph has some information, other than this no error nothing else.
[image]

Comment: While creating i am able to select or type the topic details, Could you please try to clear cache from your browser and check again. Because earlier it was a bug and it fixed as well. And try with IE . [Screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVMxe.png).

Comment: I ended up deleting function app, service bus and key vault and started from scratch and then it worked. I always use Edge in private window.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the update @*Ali*,

As a workaround which is suggested by you posting the same as solution for beneficial for other community members.

> *After deleting all the resources(e.g function app, service bus ,key
> valult) and creating again it works successfully.*

There are few more workarounds for this kind of issue,

- Please make sure that you have clear cache from the browser and use edge in your environment.

As we have tried the same to create we can able to select the topic details and also able to provide the system topic name as well.
[image]

*Our setup in local:-*

> Microsoft Edge Version 103.0.1264.37 (Official build) (64-bit)

For more information please refer this [***MICROSOFT Q&A***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/298886/can39t-create-subscription-to-azure-event-grid-top.html) discussion for the similar issues and this is for setup the [***receive notification on Expired event***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/event-grid-tutorial#create-an-event-grid-subscription)   .

*If still facing any issue please reach out to the* [***MICROSOFT Azure support***](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/) team.